# QNetwork Reply from QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt

The following code is from an example shows how to use QNetworkAccessManager to download things.

```
void Downloader::replyFinished (QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if(reply->error())
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR!";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader).toString();
        qDebug() << reply->header(QNetworkRequest::LastModifiedHeader).toDateTime().toString();
        qDebug() << reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader).toULongLong();
        qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
        qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toString();

        QFile *file = new QFile("C:/Qt/Dummy/downloaded.txt");
        if(file->open(QFile::Append))
        {
            file->write(reply->readAll());
            file->flush();
            file->close();
        }
        delete file;
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

My question is do we have to call reply->deleteLater(); here? If we don't call it, when we perform QNetworkAccessManager::get() call the second time, will the QNetworkReply* in the slot be the same QNetworkReply* ?

Comment: If you don't call deleteLater(), the QNetworkReply object will be leaked and its memory not freed. A second get() call will create a new QNetworkReply object.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld that sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Note that tools like `valgrind` will not report a leak. That's because replies are created parented to the QNAM that created them, so when you'll finally destroy that, the replies will also be deleted. It's a leak in the more broad meaning of "not freeing resources that could instead be freed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't call deleteLater(), the QNetworkReply object will be leaked and its memory not freed. A second get() call will create a new QNetworkReply object.

Comment: `QNetworkReply object will be leaked and its memory not freed.` - according to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#dtor.QNetworkAccessManager) they wont be leaked but accumulated.